# java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]- this should be true but showing false

Tags: selenium

```
package selenium;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class seleniumguru{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        FirefoxDriver  driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/v4/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement  userid=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"));
        userid.sendKeys("mngr79426");
        WebElement  password=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input"));
        password.sendKeys("ejEqasE");
        WebElement  login=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input[1]"));
        login.click();
        WebElement  manageid=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td"));
        manageid.getText();

        //To verify home page as text contains "mngr79426"
        Assert.assertTrue(manageid.equals("Manger Id : mngr79426"));
```

Comment: Can you consider working on the Answers provided by SO volunteers on your previous Questions and Accept them accordingly to Close those discussions before opening a new Question? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Provide proper explanation of your problem will help the other to get clear understanding.

Comment: Please format your code first and add some relevant explanation. Adding just a snippet of code is not going to help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing the value with webElement here

```
Assert.assertTrue(manageid.equals("Manger Id : mngr79426"));
```

Need to compare with text. Either use Below code :

```
Assert.assertTrue(manageid.getText().equals("Manger Id : mngr79426"));
```

Or store the test in a string  Like

```
String managerID = manageid.getText();
```

and now do comparison :

```
Assert.assertTrue(managerID.equals("Manger Id : mngr79426"));
```